# How to pass data between Components?

Tags: react-native

*I want to pass data to another component state. But I dont want to open that page I mean Idont want to use navigate.*

*I use componenwillmount on that page  but when data change, componenwillmount not work again.*

*I pass like this.*

```
<NewPage data={this.state.collection} />
```

*this is page1 :*

```
return (

    <View style= {styles.firstView}> 
         <View style={{flex: 1.5}}>
             <Header color1 = {Blue.length}  color2 = {Yellow.length} navigation={this.props.navigation}  setData= {this.handleSetData}/>
         </View >

             <View style={{flex: 0.5, backgroundColor:'#f2f2f2'}}>
                 <Bar />
            </View>

        <View style={{flex: 9}}>
            {/* <ScrollView>
             {this.renderall()}
            </ScrollView> */}

            <NewPage data= {this.state.collection}/>


        </View>

        <View style={styles.footerStyle}>
          <Footer />
        </View>  

    </View>
```

*this is NewPage:*

```
export default class NewPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {

    fromPage1: [],
    }

}
```

As I said everytime I want to change state which is "frompage1"

Comment: You want to pass `this.state.collection` from another component? And the above line of code is in the other component?

Comment: this.state.collection is in page1 and I want to pass this data to <Newpage> component but as I said, data can be change. So  state  where in newpage should change

Comment: And part of page1's render is `<NewPage data={this.state.collection} />`?

Comment: yes it is rendered in page1

Comment: So NewPage  is rendered anyway every time page1's state.collection changes...

Comment: I cant use this.setstate in newpage render.  because it renders always when I use. how to change state in newpage

Comment: Sorry, I lost you... I suggest that you post the code of both components.

Comment: Edited question bro

Answer (score 1):

I am quite not sure what you are asking. If I got you right, I think you are looking for something like this

```
export default class NewPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
const {data} = props;
console.log(data); //just to make sure you are getting right set of data
    this.state= {

    fromPage1: data
    }

}

// if your props are updating try
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { this.setState(fromPage1: nextProps.data)}
```

Let me know if you wanted something else.

Comment: actually it is like What I want but not exacty.  when page1 is open, data is empty and  in newpage console.log(data) gives me empty array. then when I click button in page1 data is filled. but in newpage it is not

Comment: Umm, try `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { this.setState(fromPage1: nextProps.data)}`